# How to write a Laravel validation rule where the length of an array must not be equal to 1?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, controller

I have a table and columns associated with that table. I can delete columns using this controller method:

```
public function destroy(Grid $grid, GridCol $gridCol)
{
    $this->deleteRowOrCol($grid, $gridCol);
    return $gridCol;
}
```

However, I need to add validation that prevents me from deleting that column if the number of columns = 1 (in other words, if the length of grid->grid_cols === 1.)

Note that $grid is of the following structure (simplified):

```
$grid = {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "DSFGEA",
    "client_id": 1,
    "last_grid_col": {
        "id": 41,
        "grid_id": 5,
        "order": 2,
        "header": "ABC",
    },
    "grid_cols": [
        {
            "id": 42,
            "grid_id": 5,
            "order": 1,
            "header": "WER",
        },
        {
            "id": 41,
            "grid_id": 5,
            "order": 2,
            "header": "ABC",
        }
    ],
}
```

And $gridCol is retrieved using:

```
$grid->gridCols()->where('order', $request->input('order'))->firstOrFail()
```

I know how to add validation with a minimum number in the array:

```
public function destroy(Grid $grid, GridCol $gridCol)
{
    $validatedValues = $this->validate($grid, [
        "grid_cols"    => "required|array|min:1",
    ]);

    $this->deleteRowOrCol($validatedValues, $gridCol);
    return $gridCol;
}
```

However, that’s not quite what I aim to do. How would I be able to update or add to the code below to prevent users from deleting a grid column when the number of grid_cols === 1?

Answer (score 1):

No need to use custom validation, by default laravel provided

```
$validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'grid_cols' => ['required','array','min:2'],
]);


if($validatedData->fails()) {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'No Delete the grid!','errors' => $validatedData->getMessageBag()->toArray()], 400);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function destroy(Grid $grid, GridCol $gridCol)
{
    $validatedValues = $this->validate($grid, [
        "grid_cols"    => "required|array|integer|gt:1",
    ]);

    $this->deleteRowOrCol($validatedValues, $gridCol);
    return $gridCol;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to be effective since it directly counts how many grid columns are there and throws a 422 if there's 1 item in the gridCols array:

```
    if (count($grid->gridCols) === 1)
        abort(422, 'Cannot delete last table column');
    else {
        $this->deleteRowOrCol($grid, $gridCol);
        return $gridCol;
    }
```